# How to show progress bar while loading some controls?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, progress-bar

My controls are dynamically generated when the dropdownlist is changed by user. They values are loaded from the database. How to display progressbar during the generation of control?

Comment: Try this one http://contextllc.com/tools/jQuery-showLoading. Ths perfectly fits my needs and I'm sure you'll like it too.

Comment: Guys he is not asking for a loading gif,he needs a progress bar which advances as controls are being generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add download image on the form. When user will change item in dropdownlist call the event onchange with javascript. There is example for adding handler:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           dropdownlist1.Attributes.Add("onchange", "document.getElementById(\"loading_image\").style.visibility = \"visible\";");
        }
```

Before that you must add image on the form:

```
<img style="visibility:hidden;" src="imageurl" runat="server" id="loading_image" />
```

Answer (score 1):

if(combobox.text=="type selected value")
{
load the progress bar here..
}

Answer (score 0):

After the user makes the selection, insert an `<img>` tag with an animated .gif progress bar. When the controls are returned to load onto the page, use javascript to delete the `<img>` tag and insert your controls.

Comment: I thought about it but i don't know how could i do it.

Answer (score 0):

For showing actual progress you need a Context-Sensitive progress bar. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh580729.aspx) is the article that is showing how to show actual progress through ajax of server side operations.

Comment: he is not asking for a loading gif,he needs a progress bar which advances as controls are being generated.